# Make sure promise resolved inside transformFunction

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, node-streams, through2

I am studying [through2](https://github.com/rvagg/through2) and [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html#destroying-deleting-persistent-instances).

My codes:

```
  return Doc.createReadStream({
    where: { /*...*/ },
    include: [
      {
        /*...*/
      },
    ],
  })
  .pipe(through({ objectMode: true }, (doc, enc, cb) => {
    Comment.findOne(null, { where: { onId: doc.id } }).then((com) => { /* sequelize: findOne*/
      com.destroy(); /* sequelize instance destroy: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html#destroying-deleting-persistent-instances */
      cb();
    });
  }))
  .on('finish', () => {
    console.log('FINISHED');
  })
  .on('error', err => console.log('ERR', err));
```

I am trying to express my question clearly. `Doc` and `Comment` are sequelize Models. I want to use stream to read Doc instances from database one by one and delete comments on each Doc instance. `Comment.findOne` and `com.destroy()` will both return promises. I want to the promises resolved for each `doc` and then call `cb()`. But my above codes cannot work, before `com`  be destroyed, the codes already finish running.

How to fix it? Thanks

I wrap the above piece of codes in `mocha` test, like

```
it('should be found by readstream', function _testStream(){
  /* wrap the first piece of codes here*/
});
```

But before stream finished reading, the test exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for another promise by returning the promise and using another `.then`.

You may need to check for the `com` result being `null` as well, before running `.destroy()`.

```
  .pipe(through({ objectMode: true }, (doc, enc, cb) => {
    Comment.findOne(null, { where: { onId: doc.id } })
      .then(com => com.destroy())
      .then(()=> cb())
      .catch(cb)
  }))
```

Then when running the test in mocha, you need to wait for the asynchronous stream by adding `done` to the test function signature and calling `done()` on completion or error.

```
it('should be found by readstream', function _testStream(done){
  ...
  .on('finish', () => done())
  .on('error', done)
})
```

Comment: Great. but for now, I cannot use `await`

Comment: I tried the first solution, but again, before stream finished reading, the test existed. I think the problem is that the whole promise chain is async..

Comment: Ah yes. You need to use `done` with mocha  and streams to signify the end of the async test... I'll add that in